# Set background color for individual bars using ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, chart.js

I'm attempting to model my bar chart after Chart.JS's example and have not been having any luck. This is what I'm tying to recreate:

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-introduction

For whatever reason my bar's on the graph simply come out dark gray. I have been unable to fix this. My code is below. Does anyone know how I could change my code to fix this issue?

Thanks!

```
            // bar chart data
            var barData = {
                labels : ["Counselor","Examiner","Rock","Seeker","Uniter"],

                backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',

            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',

            ],
            borderWidth: 1,


                datasets : [
                    {
                        // fillColor : "#48A497",
                        // strokeColor : "#48A4D1",
                        data : [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, ]
                    }
                ]
            }
            // get bar chart canvas
            var income = document.getElementById("income").getContext("2d");
            // draw bar chart
            new Chart(income).Bar(barData);
```

Comment: so, the labels are right and the colors not, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that the colors should be part of the dataset according to what I read in the official documentation link, try this:

```
var barData = {
                labels : ["Counselor","Examiner","Rock","Seeker","Uniter"],
                datasets : [{
                        // fillColor : "#48A497",
                        // strokeColor : "#48A4D1",
                        data : [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                }]
            }
```

Fiddle example added:
https://jsfiddle.net/hdr4uuLy/

Comment: Would you be able to make a JSFiddle?

Comment: added @AndrewLeonardi

Answer (score 0):

Bit of added info if anyone is using this...make sure this is in your head tag. I was using just Charts.JS CDN but this requires the bundle:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```